# Jquery animation jerking in drupal menu

Tags: jquery, animation

i'm working on a drupal site. And i've to make a slide menu (sliding in from right) and im using jquery animate function to fulfill my requirement. The problem is that sliding effects seems to be effected when cursor is on it. Otherwise works perfectly. Can anyone kindly guide me whats going on? Where i am wrong? Here the code and also the link to video where you can see whats happening.

```
$('#block-menu-block-1').hide();
$('.menu a#drop-link').bind('click', function(){
  $('#block-menu-block-1').animate({ right: '170px', width: 'toggle' });
});
$('#close-btn').bind('click', function(){
  $('#block-menu-block-1').animate({ right: '170px', width: 'toggle' });
});
```

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPCoIttAJQU

Answer (score 0):

here is a fix to it. implement this fix.

```
$('.menu a#drop-link').attr('click', function(){
  $('#block-menu-block-1').animate({ right: '170px', width: 'toggle' });
});
```

Comment: if im not wrong we use "attr" to add an attribute to HTML tags. This is not the solution :) I've tried it though.